# Making a picture of the whole seamless circumference of a leg?

Tags: photo-editing, product-photography, 360-panorama

I need to take a high res photo of a leg all the way around but have it as one seamless picture, is this possible for someone not experienced with professional programs? Thanks!

Comment: Like a texture for a 3D model?

Comment: Yes just a seamless 360 of a leg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you keep the lighting consistent and the angle consistent, you should be able to work your way around it taking photos and then piece them together like a panoramic image.  The more photos you use, the less distortion you will get from the curvature of the leg.

I would expect that Microsoft ICE should be able to piece the images together, though you may first have to trim away the background.

Comment: Thank you for the information, are there any easy to use programs for this as i am not very technical?

Comment: Did you try Microsoft ice?  Was that too complicated?

Comment: I haven't yet but can it stitch if i take pictures separately with an ordinary DSLR, what is the smoothest way to take the pictures ready for stitching? Thanks

Comment: take the photos as tangentially as possible so that you have flat portions of cloth all the way around